# Append to elements in existing view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've a portion of the view defined that on load may or may not be populated by the ViewModel. Then user does some interaction, like selecting categories and products and adding them to existing collection.

They way this view (it's a partial view) is setup:
User selects Categories -> Products are shown.
User selects Products -> Adds them to their collection.

Since the user can go to the previous page that defines what categories to show and come back to this page; the code looks for collection in Model and if product collection is there it renders it, if not nothing happens.

I do not know how to append to this list through jQuery. I know how to create a new one if there is no existing element.

The section of the view is defined like below:

```
<div class="span4 selected-products">
    <h4>Products to track</h4>
       <ul class="SelectedProducts">
          @foreach (var item in Model.SelectedProducts)
          { 
            <li class="network">@item.SelectedCategory.CategoryName
              <div>
                  <ul>@foreach (var net in item.CategoryNetwork)
                      {
                        <li id="@net.CategoryNetwork.NetworkId"> @net.CategoryNetwork.NetworkName
                           <div>
                               <ul>
                                  @foreach (var product in net.Products)
                                  {
                                     <li id="@product.ProdID">@product.ProdName</li> 
                                   }
                                </ul>
                             </div>
                         </li>
                       }
                     </ul>
                   </div>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
   </div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no reason to use foreach in ASP.NET MVC. Really! It is of course up to you. Framework can do it for you, why waste effort on something built in?

`@EditorFor(m => Model.SelectedProducts)` will do nicely. Define [EditorTemplate](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/) that receives `IEnumerable<yourtypeofproduct>`, in it have another `@EditorFor(Model.CategoryNetwork)` and another editor template with respective type etc....
Its convention over configuration.

1. Go to [this article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) and look for "Dynamically Adding Items". There lies your answer as to how to append more items to your existing model. Its basically making Ajax call to controller, receiving the structure you want to append and appending it using jQuery.

Hope this is of help to you.